# MATLAB unsure of how to resolve this error: Error using / Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I'm running into an error where MATLAB is saying the matrix dimensions don't agree.

[Matlab code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUwfw.png)

I looked up this error and read all the various answers and changed all of the * and / operators to .* and ./ but now it's telling me that the arrays have incompatible sizes.

I believe I'm out of my league when it comes to figuring this out. Can anyone either help me alter the code so that it can be ran, or at least point me in a direction on how to plot Fourier Series approximations.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Tried to code Fourier series approximation using Matlab and then get a plot where it showed this approximation to the fourth term, or n = 4. Ran into error with matrix dimensions. Did not get any plot.

Comment: Indeed, you must use `.*` and `./` (element-wise multiplication and division) everywhere. If you do that, where does it tell you about incompatible sizes? You should show that version of the code and that error. Please copy-paste your code and the full error message into your post, don't post images of text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/7328782

Comment: Thanks for the help, apologies for the late response. Will make sure to abide by the forum rules next time. I thought I was embedding the image but it turns out all it did was post a link to it.

Comment: An embedded image is no better than a link to an image. It's hard to read, and we can't copy-paste the code to run it ourselves. Also many people can't read it at all (and I'm not only talking about blind people here, some can't fetch images from imgur). Plus, copy-pasting text is so much faster than making a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
close all;clear all;clc
      
T=4             % cycle input periodic signal
w=2*pi/T        % frequency [rad] input periodic signal
t=-T:.0001:T;   % [s] time reference
N=16            % amount Fourier series terms
n=[1:N]';       % index
a0=0
bn=(pi./n).*(-cos(2*n*pi/3)+cos(n*pi/3)+cos(5*n*pi/3)-cos(4*n*pi/3));

A1=(a0/2)+bn.*sin(w*n*t);   % individual terms
A2=sum(A1);                 % Fourier terms sum

figure;
hold on

for k=1:1:numel(n)
    plot(t,A1(k,:))
end

plot(t,A2,'LineWidth',2.5)
grid on
```

[image]

Comment: Your help is very much appreciated! I'd ask for clarification why array multiplication and division is used in some places and not others but I fear the answer would be time consuming for you. You can consider this question "closed."

Comment: @Thxforhelping If you consider this question closed, click on the check mark icon to the left of the answer, to turn it green.

Comment: Regarding `*` vs `.*`: they do the same thing if one of the two operands is a scalar (such as `pi` or `3`).

Comment: Hi Thxforhelping, some one has closed this question. You can post another question asking for further clarifications on this QA, just let me know where do you post it and I will have a look, regards.